# How does windows decide which executable to run

Tags: windows, command-line

I have several places on my computer that have executables, and they are all added to the `PATH`.

Occasionally, there are cases where I have multiple executables with the same name that either have different configurations or do different things entirely.  For example I have the native Windows `FIND` command, and I also have the Linux port of `find` for windows.  Both of these are very useful in their own right, but do very different things.

When I execute `FIND` from the command line; by default the Windows version executes unless I am in the directory with the Unix version.  In this case, this is mostly what I want, but there are situations that are different.  I know the executable that will run will always be the one outputted when I type `which <executable name>`.

My question is:  How is that executable chosen over the other?  Why does Windows choose `Git` located at `...\msysgit\bin\git.exe` vs the one located at `D:\bin\git.exe`?  Both locations are on the `PATH`.  Is it something as silly as the order of the `PATH` entries?

Comment: Yep, the order on the `PATH` is what determines it, after looking in the current working directory.

Comment: Guess it makes sense.  Just seems dumb.

Comment: @user1167442 How is that dumb or silly?  In what order would you expect Windows to search the directories in `%PATH%` if not the order in which they are listed?  It has to start somewhere.

Comment: @BACON It does have to start somewhere I agree.  Maybe it's not dumb; it's just seems like it would be easier to manage.  To even look at it properly, I have to copy it into a text editor,replace `;` with `;\n`, then edit it and join it again.  I guess I could write a registry script - meh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Windows first checks the current working directory, then checks each path in the PATH variable from left to right, and finally checks system locations (e.g. %WINDIR%). This is almost identical to Linux, except Linux does not check "." before PATH.

Comment: Its interesting that Linux doesn't check "." first.

Comment: Linux sees this as a security risk. If someone drops an executable into your home directory, for example, you might accidentally run it instead of /usr/bin. Windows carries its behavior from MS-DOS, which had the same behavior.

Answer (score 5):

What Windows will execute is not trivial, it might even depend on the API used.

One of them is [CreateProcessW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) which documents:

> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.
> 2. The current directory for the parent process.
> 3. The 32-bit Windows system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 4. The 16-bit Windows system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched. The name of this directory is System.
> 5. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this function does not search the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. To include this per-application path in the search sequence, use the ShellExecute function.

Since Windows Vista, the environment variable %NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath% configures whether or not the current directory should be searched (Source: [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-needcurrentdirectoryforexepathw)).

Also: if you just run a command without an extension, the environment variable %PathExt% is used to find executable extensions. (Source: [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start)).

> The default value for the PATHEXT variable is: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

The text of CreateProcessW mentions [ShellExecute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea), but I could not find documentation of how that function deals with path settings.

A great tool for figuring out where exactly an executable is searched is [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). Set a filter for `path contains <executable>` (not `<executable>.exe`) and you'll see the exact search order. It will report "NO SUCH FILE" for directories which do not contain an executable.

Comment: [`OpenFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfile#remarks) mentions the same order, slightly inconsistently.