# cmd - Choose which executable to run

Tags: cmd.exe, path

Building off [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/897644/how-does-windows-decide-which-executable-to-run), is there a way to choose which convert to run while you're executing in the command prompt, or do you just have to reorder Path?

Comment: If it's not first in the path then type `c:\pathtotheothercopy\program.exe`

Comment: Well, you can always do that. I was just wondering if there was a more convenient way.

Comment: You could always write a batch file ...

Comment: Sounds like that's my best option. :(

Comment: Create Windows shortcuts to the files with the same name and give the shortcuts different names.