# Why does PATH entry order matter?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

I've seen numerous articles (see [1](https://superuser.com/questions/897644/how-does-windows-decide-which-executable-to-run/897645) [2](https://superuser.com/questions/1438906/does-order-in-windows-10-path-variable-matter) [3](http://environmentvariables.org/Path)) addressing *if* order matters with regards to entries in the `PATH` environment variable and it is clear that the answer is a resounding **yes**. However I don't understand *why* it should matter.

If `PATH` is used to resolve the locations of programs, then surely we would ideally want one program mapped to one directory when using it. If this is the case, though, then we'd never have a need to reorder entries in the `PATH` variable; there should be one directory location for each executable, so the OS would simply flip through the entries until it finds its match.

But I recently installed a python module which didn't work until I put one entry before another existing one in `PATH`. Whatever was using the entry which my new entry now precedes would apparently be searching for the same program, otherwise a problem with conflicting entries to a single program wouldn't emerge.

If I'm reordering the entries to resolve a conflict, then surely I am creating another conflict; if my new program was failing when meeting the old `PATH` entry, then surely the old program will now be failing with meeting my new entry. If not, then I could surely just remove the old entry and nothing would go awry. But if we remove the old entry, then there are no conflicts, so order doesn't matter.

Do you see what I mean? I'm going in circles here.

Answer (score 6):

PATH order matters for at least two reasons:

1. If a resource, e.g. [a DLL, is in two different versions with the same name](https://planet.jboss.org/post/fighting_the_msvcrt_dll_hell), then the one first in path is found and not the second. A program might work with only one particular DLL, or it might work with both.
2. A defective entry in PATH causes all subsequent entries to fail. If the illegitimate entry is at the end, no problem... but if moved earlier, it causes others to not work.

Work-around for issue 1. is to put legacy DLL's in the same folder as the executable. PATH is a bit of a crutch.

If others want to add to this list of reasons, feel free to do so.

Comment: "A program might work with only one particular DLL, or it might work with both."
But then we can delete one, giving us a situation where order won't matter. I understand both scenarios, but your answer leads me to suspect that the order only matters if we have bad entries.

Comment: The scenarios "not both" and "either DLL" still sounds to me like you could delete one later on the path (because it'd never be reached) to create a scenario where there are only unique entries, so order wouldn't matter. I haven't read your link yet but I will look at it soon, maybe it will resolve this contradiction for me.