# Choice command not working by double clicking on the batch file

Tags: batch-file, double-click

1. If I run the Test.bat file with a double click, I get a strange behavior.
2. If I run the Test.bat file by right clicking on the file and selecting Run as administrator, I get the correct result.

Why in case 1, the script doesn't run correctly?

Test.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
CHOICE /C:123 /N /M "PICK A NUMBER (1, 2, or 3)"
IF ERRORLEVEL == 3 GOTO THREE
IF ERRORLEVEL == 2 GOTO TWO
IF ERRORLEVEL == 1 GOTO ONE
GOTO END
:THREE
ECHO YOU HAVE PRESSED THREE
GOTO END
:TWO
ECHO YOU HAVE PRESSED TWO
GOTO END
:ONE
ECHO YOU HAVE PRESSED ONE
:END
PAUSE
```

---

**Note:**
I have been asked to clarify or edit an issue that has already been resolved.
There is nothing to clarify or change. Read the post accepted as solution carefully if you want to know the cause of the problem and how to fix it.

Please, if a problem has been solved, do not write to edit the question. We are not here to waste time!

---

Comment: What "strange behaviour" exactly? Please [edit] your question and add this vital information.

Comment: The script works for me in Win10 22H2 running with and without elevation.  Everything looks correct to me.

Comment: Share the complete batch, something in it will explain the problem. And run on the direct command line: `test.bat 2>&1 >file.log & type file.log` After. plz  post the error contained in `FIle.log`

Comment: Test 1 from folder H:\Temp - 
Test 2 from folder H:\Downloads - [Click to download](https://easyupload.io/edh8lp)

Comment: @Stackuser I think you should add that to the question via an [edit].

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice. Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// **EDIT:**

**Issue Identified:**

The presence (in the same folder that contains the `Test.bat` file) of a ***`Choice.bat`*** file containing a **[`Choice`](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html)** command.

Renaming the ***`Choice.bat`*** file fixes the issue.

**[`Test.bat`](https://pastebin.com/rJZyU2kh)** + **[`Choice.bat`](https://pastebin.com/rPD5PvZm)**

---

---

The `Test.bat` file is located in the `D:\Download` folder (containing about 12000 items). Only the `.bat` files containing the `Choice` command are not executed correctly by double-clicking.
**[image: Test.bat]**

- Issue fixed by placing the `Test.bat` file in a different folder
  The script runs correctly when double-clicking on the file.
  [image]

---

Comment: Yes, in case of the same name and files with different extensions, the command interpreter will obey the order present in **`%PathExt%`**

Comment: ***[The PathExt is an Environment Variable that stores a list of the file extensions for operation system to execute. When running a command line that does not contain an extension, the system uses the value of this environment variable to determine which extensions to look for and in what order, such as .com first, follow by .exe, .bat, .cmd, which happens to be the default value stored in the PathExt by Windows.](https://www.nextofwindows.com/what-is-pathext-environment-variable-in-windows)***

Comment: Side note: this is why [in Linux we usually don't include `.` in `PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65704/108618). Windows (especially `cmd.exe`, the interpreter of `.bat` files) [is reckless in this matter](https://superuser.com/a/897645/432690) ([hysterical raisins](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html), I think) and you get what you get.